# why assigning Value to int member of structure causing segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

These are the structure.

```
struct Contact
{
    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers numbers;
};   



struct Address
    {
        int streetNumber;
        char street[41];
        int apartmentNumber;
        char postalCode[8];
        char city[41];
    };
```

This is the structure initialisation. `MAXCONTACTS` is defined as 5.

```
struct Contact contacts[MAXCONTACTS] = {
        {   { "Rick", {'\0'}, "Grimes" },
            { 11, "Trailer Park", 0, "A7A 2J2", "King City" },
            { "4161112222", "4162223333", "4163334444" } },
        {
            { "Maggie", "R.", "Greene" },
            { 55, "Hightop House", 0, "A9A 3K3", "Bolton" },
            { "9051112222", "9052223333", "9053334444" } },
        {
            { "Morgan", "A.", "Jones" },
            { 77, "Cottage Lane", 0, "C7C 9Q9", "Peterborough" },
            { "7051112222", "7052223333", "7053334444" } },
        {
            { "Sasha", {'\0'}, "Williams" },
            { 55, "Hightop House", 0, "A9A 3K3", "Bolton" },
            { "9052223333", "9052223333", "9054445555" } },
    };
```

This array is passed to the function, `addContact(contacts, MAXCONTACTS);`. Inside addContact, we have `getContact(&contacts[emptyIndex]);`.

Inside getContact is the function call `getAddress(&contact->address);`.

This is the function,

```
void getAddress(struct Address* address)
{
    int yesNo;

    printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
    do
    {
        address->streetNumber = getInt(); // this works fine
        if (address->streetNumber < 1)
            printf("*** INVALID STREET NUMBER *** <must be a positive number>: ");
    } while (address->streetNumber < 1);

    printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
    scanf("%40[^\n]%*c", address->street);

    printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");
    yesNo = yes();

    if (yesNo == 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
        do
        {           
            address->apartmentNumber = getInt(); // this causes segmentation fault (core dumped)
            if (address->apartmentNumber < 1)
                printf("*** INVALID APARTMENT NUMBER *** <must be a positive number>: ");
        } while (address->apartmentNumber < 1);
    }
}
```

The `getInt()` function just returns a integer value, if character value is provided it prompts again. This function is fine. But as soon as it return a value (positive or negative), it causes segmentation fault (core dumped).

I even tried manually assigning a value `address->apartmentNumer = 0`, throws the same error. This is something I am not getting.

Identical approach with `address->streetNumber` works fine. No errors there.

Comment: You have a pointer to an `Address` structure, but is that pointer valid to begin with? How do you call this `getAddress` function? What is the pointer actually pointing to?

Comment: We need to see how `contact` is defined/initialized. It is probably `NULL` or out-of-range of memory and `&contact->address` would have the same issues [in the caller], so `address->apartmentNumber` [in the subfunction] is where it faults but not the origin of the bad value

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Comment: I have added required details and edited the question.

Comment: Please upgrade the collection of code fragments to a [mre].